# Extract value from json-array in ApacheCamel header

Tags: apache-camel, jsonpath

I want to extract a value from a JSON-array inside a header using jsonpath.

headers.barcodes:

```
 [ { "barcodeValue" : "123456789" , "type" : "CODE128" , `"pageNumber" : 1}]
```

The only way I've found is to use the body to extract the value:

```
<setBody>
  <simple>${headers.barcodes}</simple>
</setBody>
<setHeader headerName="barcodeValueOnly">
   <jsonpath>$[0].barcodeValue</jsonpath>
</setHeader>
```

I have tried to pass the header like this:

`<jsonpath>${headers.barcodes}[0].barcodeValue</jsonpath>`

but all I get is

> com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Could not parse token starting at position 2. Expected ?, ', 0-9, *

Is there any way to pass the header value directly to jsonpath without using the body?

Comment: An alternative solution (until the functionality is added to Camel) could also be to add an inline processor. You can then extract the json string into a normal variable. Use actual jsonpath API to extract the value. You don't then need to set it in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible on jsonpath, but we have such functionality on other languages like xpath, where there is an `headerName` option you can configure to tell it to take the input from that header instead of the message body.

So I have logged a ticket to add such a functionality in the next release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11796